Snap Store Loading Updates - Endless
The Snap Store never stops 'loading updates' so I can't update through the Snap Store.
I know that's not the only way to update apps, but the Snap Store seems like something that should work without issue on Ubuntu, right? I'd like to learn what might be wrong and what I can do to fix it.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
The longer story:
I upgraded to 24.04.1 the other day. This was my first time upgrading Ubuntu (I'm still a very green user). It was a mostly smooth process. It locked up a couple of times; I restarted the PC a couple of times. Once it finally got going, it said a partial upgrade was suggested due to some third party app obstruction (most likely Fade In). From there on out, though, things ran just fine.
As far as I can tell, there are only two issues with the new install. The first is Ghost Writer (the full screen mode doesn't work. Not a big loss. I reported the bug. We'll see if it gets fixed.) The second is the Snap Store which, even after being left to load updates for 30 minutes, just keeps loading.
Does anyone know what might be wrong and what I can do to fix it?
Thank you!
Update:
Per amar's suggestion, I ran: killall snap-store, as well as: sudo snap update, which returned the following: error: unknown command "update", see 'snap help'.
As some probably know, 'snap help' returned a list of commands, not any helpful info.
Then I ran: sudo apt install -f, which returned: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded
:sudo snap refresh returned: all snaps are up to date
Per user535733's suggestion, I 'Quit' Ubuntu Software using: snap-store --quit then ran: snap-store and received the following:
sw@Bilbo:~$ snap-store --quit
16:30:38:0957 Gtk Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
sw@Bilbo:~$ snap-store
16:31:00:0210 Gtk Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
Graylist: app;application;package;program;programme;suite;tool
16:31:00:0523 PK  unhandled property 'Sender'
16:31:00:0561 Gs  lost session service
16:31:00:0561 Fwupd fwupd_client_download_bytes_async: assertion 'url != NULL' failed
16:31:00:0561 Fwupd fwupd_client_download_bytes_async: assertion 'url != NULL' failed
16:31:01:0451 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
16:31:02:0346 PK  unhandled property 'Sender'
16:31:03:0107 PK  unhandled property 'Sender'
16:31:03:0297 PK  unhandled property 'Sender'

The logs for that time read:
10:34:16 AM kernel: logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C537.0004: Unexpected input report number 128
 9:22:18 AM systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-3089.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
 9:22:16 AM gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
 9:22:09 AM (uetoothd): sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)

Please let me know if I've messed up or mis-followed your suggestions, as well as what you think might be wrong and/or what more I can do to troubleshoot this.
Thank you!
Update #2
Amar: I opened it manually.
user535733
$ snap list snap-store
Name        Version           Rev   Tracking         Publisher   Notes
snap-store  41.3-77-g7dc86c8  1113  latest/stable/…  canonical✓
Thanks, again, for the help!


@user535733, I thought that's exactly what I did. "I'd like to learn what might be wrong and what I can do to fix it."

your snap.store may not have been updated use killall snap-store and after that  sudo snap update. also check your software by running sudo apt install -f all the commands should be run in terminal and if you get an unfavorable answer edit your question do not put it in comments.

Sorry I meant Sudo snap refresh

Before, when it was loading updates, did you start the snap store or did it start by itself?

Please add the complete output of snap list snap-store to your question above.

run snap info snap-storeif it is not 41.3-77 then run sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-24.04
